# AVAudioPlayer is causing leaks under ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, avaudioplayer

I have a class that provides a Music Player, compiled under ARC. This is the init code:

```
- (id) init{
  self = [super init];
  runningVolumeNotification = FALSE;

  MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
  systemVolume = musicPlayer.volume;

  NSString *myExamplePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"servo" ofType:@"mp3"];
  AVAudioPlayer* p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
  [p prepareToPlay];
  [p stop];

  return self;
```

}

Instruments reports a 100% leak on the line:

```
AVAudioPlayer* p = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];
```

[image]

I can't figure out where the problem is!